# What is the best way to upload files with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am using jQuery and love it.

I need to allow users to upload files. What's the best solution?

- a "standard" solution would be better
- bonus points for drag and drop of files from the desktop
- bonus points for allowing file upload + other parameters in my mvc server app

Comment: You cant even give bonus points :( way to get my hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the ***best*** AJAX file uploader:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: @user380719 - This is a quote from the very page I linked to: `tested in IE7,8; Firefox 3,3.6,4; Safari4,5; Chrome; Opera10.60;`!!

Answer (score 1):

I personally have used [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and I agree with jlg, it is not a good plugin. Every version of this plugin works differently and has different function names and the last version does not work with IE. I suggest [Ajax Upload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) which works fine with ASP.net and also [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) for PHP

Answer (score 0):

What I used before I switched to the AJAX ControlToolkit was uploadify. http://www.uploadify.com/
I couldn't ever get it to work because it clashed with other plugins that were on the site so I deleted everything and am just using the AJAX Controls for my ASP site.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use an ajax upload library someone has created and customize for your needs. I personally have used [ajaxUpload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), but any library will probably do what you need.